# Problem with transliteration of 'φ' to 'f' in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

On our SQL Server 2005 machine, I encountered a bug where all the 'f' characters were getting dropped when preparing data for a downstream system that has some character limitations.

What I found was that there was a statement in a UDF that was attempting to replace 'φ' characters with ''. The problem is that, at least in our installation of SQL Server, 'φ' and 'f' are the same thing.

Can someone tell me what would be the best way to differentiate between 'φ' and 'f'?

example:

```
select case when 'φ' = 'f' then 'equal' else 'not equal' end
```

For me, this returns 'equal'

Comment: What **collation** do you have on your server and in your database??

Comment: Just checked.  It is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `N'φ'` in the string literal so it doesn't get coerced into the default collation.

For me (under `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`)

```
select case when 'φ' = 'f' then 'equal' else 'not equal' end /*equal*/

select case when N'φ' = 'f' then 'equal' else 'not equal' end /*not equal*/
```